# Return struct after parsing json in Swift

Tags: json, swift, struct

I am writing a function that calls stock exchange api and returns basic data about specific stock. After that I parse the data into my struct, but then I am not able to return this struct when I add the return statement.

This function compiles without any troble and works as expected.

```
func getData(symbol: String){


        let apiURL = "https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/\(symbol)/quote?token=\(secretToken)"
        let url = URL(string: apiURL)!

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

        guard let data = data else { return  }

            do {
                let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Stock.self, from: data)
                let stockResult = Stock(symbol: json.symbol,
                                        companyName: json.companyName,
                                        latestPrice: json.latestPrice
                )

                //I want to return this Stock structure



            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serialising json: ", jsonErr)
            }
        }.resume()

    }
```

But when I add the following code, i get an error saying ***Unexpected non-void return value in void function***

```
func getData(symbol: String) -> Stock {


        let apiURL = "https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/\(symbol)/quote?token=\(secretToken)"
        let url = URL(string: apiURL)!

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

        guard let data = data else { return  }

            do {
                let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Stock.self, from: data)
                let stockResult = Stock(symbol: json.symbol,
                                        companyName: json.companyName,
                                        latestPrice: json.latestPrice
                )

                //I want to return this Stock structure

                return stockResult

            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serialising json: ", jsonErr)
            }
        }.resume()

    }
```

any way i can force it to compile and return my stock struct?

Comment: You need to use completion handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. You have to add a closure and then use it when calling the function.

```
func getData(symbol: String, completion: @escaping (Stock) -> Void) {


        let apiURL = "https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/\(symbol)/quote?token=\(secretToken)"
        let url = URL(string: apiURL)!

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

        guard let data = data else { return  }

            do {
                let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Stock.self, from: data)
                let stockResult = Stock(symbol: json.symbol,
                                        companyName: json.companyName,
                                        latestPrice: json.latestPrice
                )

                //I want to return this Stock structure

                completionBlock(stockResult)

            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serialising json: ", jsonErr)
            }
        }.resume()

    }
```

then in the main you call

```
getData(symbol: "aapl") {(output) in
            print(output)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your function have a `completion` parameter, like so:

```
func getData(symbol: String, completion: @escaping (Stock?) -> (Void) ) {
    ...
}
```

and invoke that when you've parsed the result

```
let stockResult = Stock(...)
completion(stockResult)
```

and in case of an error, call `completion(nil)`

Generally speaking, don't fight the asynchronous nature of network calls.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have network call in your function, you should use a callback to return data.

```swift
func getData(symbol: String, completion: @escaping ((Stock?)-> Void)) {


        let apiURL = "https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/\(symbol)/quote?token=\(secretToken)"
        let url = URL(string: apiURL)!

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

        guard let data = data else { return  }

            do {
                let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Stock.self, from: data)
                let stockResult = Stock(symbol: json.symbol,
                                        companyName: json.companyName,
                                        latestPrice: json.latestPrice
                )

                // Here return your completion like this
                completion(stockResult)

            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serialising json: ", jsonErr)
            }
        }.resume()

    }
```

you can call your function like this in your controller or ViewModel :

```swift
getData(symbol: "yoursymbol") { stock in
    // process your stock
}
```